# NodeJS, ExpressJS - reloading does not refresh the page properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a very strange problem.

I am using NodeJS with ExpressJS. I have also enabled "passport" module to authenticate the user.

I have the following route

```
app.get("/home", ensureLoggedIn("/login"), (req, res) ->
    res.render "home",
        title:"Home"
)
```

Which works fine after user logs in for the first time.

Now when I am in "localhost:3000/home" and I refresh, the it seems like not all the CSS and JS files are being loaded, so my Chrome just keeps "loading" (the spinning image).

When I look at my console, I've got the following logs being printed out

```
GET /home 200 14ms - 1.32kb <-- first time page being loaded...
GET /css/main.css 304 19ms
GET /js/libs/handlebars.min.js 304 12ms
GET /js/libs/underscore-min.js 304 19ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js 304 21ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js 304 26ms
GET /js/libs/backbone-min.js 304 19ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js 304 31ms

GET /home 304 18ms <-- second time page being loaded
GET /js/libs/underscore-min.js 304 14ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js 304 16ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js 304 15ms
GET /js/libs/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js 304 15ms
```

At first it seemed like it was a particular JS file, so I took the "jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js" file out, but it happens again on another JS file I trying to load.

I thought it was something to do with the "passport" module, so I took the "ensureLoggedIn" code OUT but it's still happening.

Any ideas?

## update

Once the browser "hangs" and doesn't load anything, I can't go anywhere. I type in any URL in the browser to get the any of the assets (e.g. CSS files, JS files, images) or paths, the it just keeps loading and there is nothing in the console log.

## UPDATE2

This is getting more strange. So here's what I did. When I go to a route

```
app.get("/home", (req, res) ->
    res.render "home",
        title:"Home"
)
```

With my (very simple) home.jade file

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
head
  body
```

Everything works fine. I can refresh the page many multiple times and there's no problem.

Then I enable "passport" module and go to

```
app.get("/home", ensureLoggedIn("/login"), (req, res) ->
    res.render "home",
        title:"Home"
)
```

I can login successfully and my "home" (home.jade) file displays correctly. And here's the kicker. I refresh exactly 16 times and then on the 17th time, the page hangs.

I stop my NodeJS server and restart and the exactly the same thing, works up to 16 refreshes and on the 17th, it stops.

I feel like there is a some sort of "request" limit in passport module? Or I just might be going crazy.

## Resolved

I've found my problem - a rookie mistake - I was using Postgres as my DB and for each query, I wasn't "closing" the connection properly. So each time I refreshed, it opened a new connection to the DB - silly, silly.

Comment: A few questions: By "it seems like the CSS and JS" files are not being loaded, do you mean that the page is appearing unstyled? Are you getting any warnings in your chrome console? or Does this issue present itself in other browsers?

Comment: Tested on different browsers - same thing happens. There are no errors on Chrome console log. On my terminal, (as I posted), not all JS files and CSS file are loaded when I refresh the page.